# Copy an image from cache of web browser control present in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, browser

I know that an image can be downloaded from a website opened in web browser control, but that actually works by getting the image URL and download that. There is a website that doesn't allow the direct link, so the image fails to download, so the only method I can think of is copying the images from the cache of the web browser control.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274329/load-image-from-webbrowser-without-redownloading-or-copying

Comment: on it seems good but it seems to be in C#, can you help please

Answer (score 1):

You can use online c# to vb.net converters like [telerik](http://converter.telerik.com/) or [developerfusion](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/) to get code in vb.net in the future.

1. Add reference to Microsoft.mshtml to your project
2. Add next code into the webBrowser DocumentCompleted event handler

Sample code:

```
Private Sub webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, _
   e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) _
   Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted

   Dim doc As IHTMLDocument2 = _
      DirectCast(webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument, IHTMLDocument2)

   Dim imgRange As IHTMLControlRange = _
      DirectCast(DirectCast(doc.body, _
      HTMLBody).createControlRange(), IHTMLControlRange)

   For Each img As IHTMLImgElement In doc.images
    imgRange.add(DirectCast(img, IHTMLControlElement))

    imgRange.execCommand("Copy", False, Nothing)

    Using bmp As Bitmap = DirectCast( _
        Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap), Bitmap)
        bmp.Save("C:\" + img.nameProp)
    End Using
   Next

End Sub
```

Comment: why does it say IHTMLDocument2 not defined? I have added the reference to mshtml already.. and same error for IHTMLControlRange and IHTMLImgElement

Comment: ok that issue is resolved, but files not not saved and not even on clipboard

Comment: doc.images collection will enumerate only main document images (top frame), maybe your images are under frames collection

Comment: @user64: How do I do the same thing but to the pictures inside a particular iFrame?

Comment: use the Frames property, sample code is in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlwindow.frames.aspx