# Copying pictures from inside an iFrame in webbrowser control

Tags: vb.net, iframe, webbrowser-control

I used the code below to successfully get a copy of each picture inside a page loaded using webbrowser control.

```
    Dim doc As IHTMLDocument2 = DirectCast(wb.Document.DomDocument, IHTMLDocument2)
Dim imgRange As IHTMLControlRange = DirectCast(DirectCast(doc.body, HTMLBody).createControlRange(), IHTMLControlRange)
For Each img As IHTMLImgElement In doc.images
  imgRange.add(DirectCast(img, IHTMLControlElement))

  imgRange.execCommand("Copy", False, Nothing)

  Using bmp As Bitmap = DirectCast( _
      Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap), Bitmap)
    bmp.Save(img.nameProp)
  End Using
Next
```

I got the code from here: [Copy an image from cache of web browser control present in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877897/copy-an-image-from-cache-of-web-browser-control-present-in-vb-net)

However, the picture I am interested in is inside an iFrame.

I tried changing:

```
Dim doc As IHTMLDocument2 = DirectCast(wb.Document.DomDocument, IHTMLDocument2)
```

to

```
Dim doc As IHTMLDocument2 = DirectCast(wb.Document.Window.Frames(iFrameID).Document.DomDocument, IHTMLDocument2)
```

but I am getting an "Access Denied" Error. I guess (not sure) its because the iframe's src is on a different domain.

Is there a way around this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the iFrame has content from a domain that is different from the the parent then your out of luck. You could attempt a different solution and retrieve the iFrame's page via Ajax and parse out the image src. Another alternative is to do it server side with a program like PhantomJs (or VB, PHP etc) to retrieve the page and parse it for images to retrieve.

Comment: Is it possible to determine the URL of the page that is loaded in the iFrame?

Comment: You can get the "source" of the the iFrame using document.getElementById("theiframe").src, but if the iFrames navigation has changed then it won't work. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44359/how-do-i-get-the-current-location-of-an-iframe.

Comment: That's the first thing I had tried but I keep getting an error reading "'src' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement'." I'm not too worried about the contents of the iframe changing since there is a delay.

When in the browser, right clicking on the picture in the iFrame allows me to copy the picture I am interested in. Do you know if I can emulate that in webbrowser control programmatically?

Comment: The reference is to an HtmlWindow object (Dim cf1Frame As HtmlWindow = WebBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames("theiframe")) so the Url property should give you the url.

Comment: Now I get "'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll" :(